# How many degrees of freedom in 4D space

Tags: combinatorics

- In 1D there is 1 translational and 0 rotational d.o.f.
- In 2D there are 2 translational and 1 rotational d.o.f.
- In 3D there are 3 translational and 3 rotational d.o.f.

this would suggest there are 4 translational and 6 rotational d.o.f in 4D

My query is, is that all? Are there other other types of d.o.f. that are neither rotational nor translational?

If there are no others, is there any reason why degrees of freedom only depend on 1 or 2 axes?

Presumably, in ND we have  d.o.f. $= \binom{N}{1} + \binom{N}{2}$ for $N \geq 2$

Thanks in advance for any help.

***I don't know what tag to give this.***

Comment: The isometry group of $\Bbb R^n$ is a Lie group of dimension $n+\binom n2$. It is the semidirect product of $\Bbb R^n$ with $O(n)$.

Comment: (1) Depending on your preference, you are missing reflections. (2) In any case, read these articles on [Euclidean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group) and [Orthogonal group over Reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Over_the_real_number_field).  The latter shows (proves? hints at?) why there is a $2$ in the second term ${N \choose 2}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown if you post that as an answer you can have some more Rep :)