# How do you get 6 rotational dimensions instead of 4 in 4D space?

Tags: general-topology

I saw that in 4D space, there are 4 translational and 6 rotational degrees of freedom (dof) in [this Robotics intro video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/modernrobotics-course1/lecture/V4Cle/degrees-of-freedom-of-a-rigid-body-chapter-2-through-2-1) but couldn't figure out how he got 6. I am not trying to find an extension in higher dimensions like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183789/how-many-degrees-of-freedom-in-4d-space) which doesn't have an answer yet but that's where my research landed.

Rather, I am trying to visualize (or reason) how to get the 6 rotational degrees of freedom. If in 3D space, there are 3 rotational dof, why/how do we have more than 4 rotational dof in 4D space?

Comment: In $n\geq 2$ dimensions, a rotation happens in a plane. So out of $n$ dimensions you need to choose 2 of them for a rotation. So how many ways are there to choose 2 objects from 4 (or $n$ more generally)? What happens when $n=3$?

Comment: Using combinations. n choose 2. Could you make this answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $n \geq 2$ dimensions, a rotation happens in a plane. So out of $n$ dimensions you need to choose 2 of them for a rotation. So how many ways are there to choose 2 objects from $n$. What does this evaluate to when $n=2,3,4,...$ respectively?

Strictly speaking the first paragraph shows there are atleast $n$ choose 2 'independent' rotations. We still have to prove that these are all of them, i.e that every rotation can be 'decomposed' into a product (composition) of such elementary rotations. I'll leave aside this slightly technical question, since I think the first part atleast gets you to the number 6

Answer (score 0):

In 4D space, you rotate *around* (not in, as the first answer here says!) a plane. Yes, I mean an infinite plane with no edges, and you can build a hoop - heck, you could build a needle's eye - around that if you were a 4D critter in 4D space.

The best way to understand this is dimensional analogy. In 2 dimensions, you rotate a figure about a point. That's 0-dimensional. In 3 dimensions, you rotate about a line - an axis. That's 1-dimensional. Thus one should expect to rotate about a 2-dimensional "axis" in 4 dimensions.

So how many planes do you need to rotate around to orient an object in 4D space? Well, just as in 3D space you need one rotation for each coordinate axis, in 4D space you need one rotation for each plane that can be formed from the 4 coordinate axes. And there are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ such planes.